# tcolorbox and wrapfig: wierd spacing and tikzpicture overflowing out of tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox, wrapfig

## Context

I want to display a figure alongside some text in the `lower` part of a `tcolorbox`, and I want to encapsulate this figure inside another `tcolorbox`, but I also want text to be wrapped around it, so I am using `wrapfig` as well.

## Problem

The `tikzpicture` (that is meant to be the figure) keeps protruding out of the `tcolorbox` and `wrapfigure` environments. Furthermore, the vertical alignment of the spilling `tikzpicture` vertically stretches out the `tcolorbox`, which is undesirable.

## MWE

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[fixamsmath]{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter {\pars}  {  (      }     {  )      }
\DeclarePairedDelimiter {\bracs} {  [      }     {  ]      }

\usepackage[dvipsnames, cmyk]{xcolor}

% Floats
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{calc}

%% Customising floats
\tcbuselibrary{%
    skins,
    theorems,
    breakable
}
\tcbset{%
    shield externalize
}

\usetikzlibrary{%
    decorations.pathreplacing,
    decorations.markings,
    arrows.meta,
    positioning,
    intersections,
    external
}

%%% Custom tcolorboxes
\NewTCBox
    {\sectionbox}
    { O{Violet} !O{} }  % 1: colour, 2: extra options
    {
        on line,
        arc=7pt,
        colback=#1!2.5!white,
        colframe=#1!90!black,
        colupper=#1,
        boxrule=1pt,
        boxsep=0pt,
        left=6.5pt,
        right=3pt,
        top=3pt,
        bottom=3pt,
        before upper={\rule[-2.5pt]{0pt}{10pt}},
        #2
    }

%%%% Custom lengths
\newlength{\widthofexplanation}
\settowidth{\widthofexplanation}{\widthof{\sectionbox{\textbf{Explanation:}}}}
\addtolength{\widthofexplanation}{5mm}

\newlength{\setbackwidthofexplanation}
\setlength{\setbackwidthofexplanation}{\widthofexplanation}
\addtolength{\setbackwidthofexplanation}{1mm}

\NewTColorBox
    {solutionbox}
    { O{Solution:} O{Violet} !O{} }  % 1: before title declaration, 2: colour, 3: extra options
    {
        enhanced,
        detach title,
        coltitle=#2,
        colframe=#2,
        colback=white,
        before upper*={\hspace{-\setbackwidthofexplanation}\makebox[\widthofexplanation][b]{\sectionbox{\textbf{#1}}}~\parindent15pt\noindent},
        before lower*={\hspace{-\setbackwidthofexplanation}\makebox[\widthofexplanation][b]{\sectionbox{\textbf{Explanation:}}}~\parindent15pt\noindent},
        left=\widthofexplanation,
        #3
    }

\NewTColorBox
    [use counter=figure]
    {figurebox}
    { s O{\textbf{Figure \thetcbcounter:}~} O{6cm} m !O{} }  % {1: left or not, 2: before title declaration, 3: width, 4: title, 5: extra options}
    {
        enhanced,
        title=#4,
        fonttitle=\scriptsize,
        colframe=red,
        before title=#2,
        arc=3.5mm,
        sharp corners=downhill,
        width=#3,
        boxsep=0pt,
        left=1pt,
        right=1pt,
        top=1pt,
        bottom=1pt,
        leftrule=\IfBooleanTF{#1}{3mm}{0.5mm},  % initial is 0.5mm
        rightrule=\IfBooleanTF{#1}{0.5mm}{3mm},  % initial is 0.5mm
        add to list={figures}{figure},
        #5
    }

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}  % for dummy text

\begin{document}

\begin{solutionbox}
    \( \bracs*{ \frac12, 1 } \)
    %
    \tcblower
    %
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{6.1cm}
        \begin{figurebox}{A visual representation of the explanation using the unit circle}[center upper, valign=center, halign=center]
            % \begin{adjustbox}{width=0.9\linewidth}
                \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25, baseline=(current bounding box.south)]
                    \clip[] (-5, -0.25) rectangle (5, 5);
                    \draw[very thin, -{Stealth[length=3pt]}]                        (0, -1.25) -- (0, 1.25) node[pos=1, font=\tiny, right] {$y$};
                    \draw[very thin, {Stealth[length=3pt]}-{Stealth[length=3pt]}]   (-1.25, 0) -- (1.25, 0) node[pos=1, font=\tiny, right] {$x$};
                    \draw[very thin]                                                (0,0) circle[radius=1];

                    \draw[densely dashed, dash pattern={on 1pt off 1pt}]            (0,0) -- (30:1) node[gray, above, sloped, font=\tiny, inner sep=0, outer sep=1pt, pos=0.5] {\( \pi/6 \)} node[circle, fill=black, inner sep=0, minimum size=2pt] {} node[right, font=\tiny] {\( \pars*{ \frac{\sqrt3}2, \frac12 } \)};
                    \draw[densely dashed, dash pattern={on 1pt off 1pt}]            (0,0) -- (150:1) node[gray, above, sloped, font=\tiny, inner sep=0, outer sep=1pt, pos=0.5] {\( 5\pi/6 \)} node[circle, fill=black, inner sep=0, minimum size=2pt] {} node[left, font=\tiny] {\( \pars*{ -\frac{\sqrt3}2, \frac12 } \)};
                    \draw[densely dashed, dash pattern={on 1pt off 1pt}]            (0,0) -- (90:1) node[gray, right, font=\tiny, inner sep=0, outer sep=1pt, pos=0.75] {\( \pi/2 \)} node[circle, fill=black, inner sep=0, minimum size=2pt] {} node[above left, outer sep=2.5pt, inner sep=0, font=\tiny] {\( \pars*{ 0, 1 } \)};

                    \draw[gray, densely dashed, dash pattern={on 1pt off 1pt}, opacity=0.75, -{Stealth[length=3pt]}] (30:1.05) arc(30:150:1.05);
                    % \useasboundingbox (-5, -0.25) rectangle (5, 5);
                \end{tikzpicture}
            % \end{adjustbox}
        \end{figurebox}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    
    %
    \lipsum[1]
\end{solutionbox}

\end{document}
```

## Image

[image: A picture of the PDF of my document with the tikzpicture spilling out and the tcolorbox vertically stretched.]

Comment: remove the `\clip[] (-5, -0.25) rectangle (5, 5);`. With it you are making your image large.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you! This worked!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is answered in the comments.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Can you convert your comment into an answer? IMHO it could help others too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove in your tikzpicture the `\clip[] (-5, -0.25) rectangle (5, 5);`.

With it you are setting a bounding box and so make your image large.